# Parsing number in flutter/dart

Tags: parsing, flutter, dart, double

I'm trying to parse the string "78,74"(which is a valid number in Brazil's format) to double, but I'm getting Format Exception and I can't find any way to parse it... Already searched in intl docs but there's nothing helpful.

I don't want to replace the "," with "." because i think that it must be a way to parse it using `CultureInfo`

My code is like

```
String x = "78,74";

double d = double.tryParse(x)
```

Comment: By default it is the way `double.tryParse(x)` behaving. I dont know something like that you are mentioning exist with yet Flutter(not sure). Why cant you **replace comma if exist and replace it with dot and parse using `replaceAll`**

Comment: Yeah, after more research I think that its the only way... Using replaceAll did the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `double d = NumberFormat('pt_Br').parse(x)` from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) library. You will need to add the dependencies.

Comment: The locale is the 2nd parameter : `NumberFormat('', 'pt_Br').parse(x)` works

Answer (score 1):

Localization support for parsing numbers can be found in [package:intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl). For this particular case, you're looking for the [parse method from NumberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat/).