# Flutter/Dart - Parse

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

This is a question on how to parse numbers in different countries correctly. For example, I'd like to parse numbers that use a comma as a decimal point separator. (e.g. in France, 'one and half' is written as 1,5 with comma, not 1.5 as in the U.S).

In the following code, I am expecting the variable 'd' contains 1.2 because the comma in '1,2' is the decimal separator in France. However the variable d contains '12.0'. Why?

```
String amountAsString = '1,2';
double d = NumberFormat('fr_FR').parse(amountAsString);
```

[image]

I did refer to [Parsing number in flutter/dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048730/parsing-number-in-flutter-dart). Also, it's not an option to blindly replace ',' to '.' before parsing. Thanks!

**Edit**

By writing as shown in the screenshot below, I was able to make the tests pass (the first 4 tests below passed). The FormatException for the last case is actually good as '10.5' is not a correct format for French. If there is a better way, I'd like to know. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by writing like the screenshot under the Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` doesn't have to be blindly, there is usually a work around. But you can also use `NumberFormat` with the correct ***pattern*** to ensure that the decimal separator is set to the `,`

```
String amountAsString = '1,2';
NumberFormat a = NumberFormat('#,##0.0#', 'fr_FR');
num n = a.parse(amountAsString); //NumberFormat.parse always returns a num type value
double d = n.toDouble(); //convert num to double
```

`#` is a placeholder for a digit. If digit is present, it will be shown or otherwise omitted.
`0` is same as `#` but if no digit is present it will display a 0

you can read more about patterns from the [NumberFormat documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html)

Comment: Thanks @Texv. The solution might be OK if the target language is just French, but for my case, the number of target languages is so many, and I really would like to avoid specifying different number format for different languages.

Comment: hmm im not sure how to automatically do it without hardcoding except with .replace. is there a reason why you cant use amountAsString.replaceFirst(',', '.')?

Comment: I don't think I can just replace a comma to a dot because some countries use comma as a thousand separator. E.g. '$10,000' mean ten thousand dollars in the U.S. If I replace comma to a dot, it begins to mean $10. These rules are different in various countries and I am hoping an existing library knows the rules for different countries.

Comment: yes but you can make the function conditional based on the country